# How to add new post in first row in listview.?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

When i click the add button item will be added in list view but i need add that post first row of the list view like Facebook new post. thanks for your suggestion.

```
list.add(edit.getText().toString());
 edit.setText("");
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: did you try list.add(0, edit.getText().toString()) ?

Comment: @nr4bt i have small dought when i'm getting data from web services and added to listview is it working or not.

Comment: do you mean you want to check if you get the data correctly or not?

Comment: @nr4bt not like that. I have add new post in my application in any screen but that post will be added in first row in the list view in first screen.

Comment: I didn't really get it, sorry. Could you give more details?

Answer (score 1):

In order to help others who may have the same issue. Inserting item to the list in the first place would do the trick.

```
list.add(0, edit.getText().toString());
```